# Implication, propositional logic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

P: n is divided by 2.
Q:  n is an even number.
Here n belongs to integer numbes only.
How does it follow the truth table of 'if P then Q' ?
In truth table,  if truth value of P is false and Q is true then How the whole statement is true.

Comment: Your question is extremely ill-phrased. Did you mean: $P(x)$ indicates whether or not $x$ is divisible by $2$, and $Q(x)$ indicates whether or not $x$ is an even number?

Comment: In any case, I guess that what you really want to ask is how can the expression "false $\implies$ true" can be true, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: In this case, $P $ and $Q$ are equivalent.  We have both $P\to Q$, and $Q\to P$, so, when their truth values match, $(P\to Q)\land (Q\to P)$ is true only when each conjucnts are true, or both are false.

Comment: You're welcome, shashikant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the universe of discourse is all integers (or natural numbers?)

Note that  any integer divisible by $2$ is even.

$$\forall n\in \mathbb Z(P(n) \rightarrow Q(n))$$ 
For all integers n, if $2\mid n$, then $n$ is an even number.

Also, we have, that every $$\forall n\in \mathbb Z(Q(n)\rightarrow P(n))$$

If you use the truth-table for $P\leftrightarrow Q$, you'll find that $P$ and $Q$ are either both true, or else both false.

In the end, we see that $\forall n \in \mathbb Z( P(n) \iff Q(n))$

To simplify matters, we will discuss $P$ to mean "$2\mid n$"  and $Q$ to mean "n is even."

Because $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent, by definition, $P \leftrightarrow Q$.

If you use the truth-table for $P\leftrightarrow Q$, you'll find it is true only when $P$ and $Q$ are either both true, or else both false.
[image]